# Building jar with maven-scala-plugin

Tags: eclipse, maven-2, scala, m2eclipse

I created scala application and now I want to build jar.
I run `mvn package` than I try to run jar by command

`java -jar target/burner-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`

and I see error:

`Failed to load Main-Class manifest attribute from`

How can I define Main-Class property?
Do I need to create Manifest.mf? where?
Or I need to have mainclass property somewhere in pom.xml?

**Update:**
I have created src/main/resources/MANIFEST.MF file with contents

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
Created-By: Apache Maven
Built-By: itsabear
Main-Class: ru.dmteam.App
Build-Jdk: 1.6.0_20
```

I did not forget line ending at the end of file.
after `mvn package` I see new jar. I checked manifest.mf in this jar - it contains right main-class but when I type `java -jar target/burner-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar` I still see an error `Failed to load Main-Class manifest attribute from`

My pom.xml http://pastie.org/1070483

**UPDATE 2**
I discovered that now there are two manifest.mf files in the jar.
MANIFEST.MF and META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
I moved my custom MANIFEST.MF to just created META-INF folder(in src/main/resources) but now  `mvn package` overrides it while creating jar...

Comment: Can you post a copy of your pom.xml? You should be able to do this within Maven without resorting to manually creating a manifest file.

Comment: I discovered some new facts and updated the post.

Comment: Are the scala files being added to your jar? This would explain why the 'java -jar' command is not working while the 'scala -cp' is. You can package the scala dependencies using the maven-assembly-plugin (I think you can also specify the default main class here as well).

Comment: hmm... There are no scala files in my jar.
I will try to recreate pom.xml(now it is terrible) according to maven-scala-plugin guide. If this will not help I'll try maven assembly.

Comment: Now I have created new pom.xml - http://pastie.org/1070524 and built jar with mvn assembly:assembly. I can run jar with command `java -jar target/final_name-jar-with-dependencies.jar`. Is it possible to make mvn automatically generate MANIFEST.MF with Main-Class option?

Comment: You should be good to go if you add

<archive><manifest><mainClass>org.sample.App</mainClass></manifest></archive>

under the 'configuration' node of maven-assembly-plugin. You'll probably have to get rid of your manual Manifest file as well.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

After creating a new maven project using the scala-archetype-simple archetype (A simple project that prints 'Hello World'), I needed to add the following to my pom.xml

```
   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2-beta-5</version>
    <configuration>
      <descriptorRefs>
        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
      </descriptorRefs>
      <archive>
        <manifest>
          <mainClass>test.App</mainClass>
        </manifest>
      </archive>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>single</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

for the class *test.App* to run as desired when invoked with the command

```
java -jar ./target/mytest-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

After running the command

```
mvn package
```

Comment: When I type mvn package I see error `'single' was specified in an execution, but not found in the pluin`
'

Comment: so now I can build working jar by command mvn assembly:assembly but I need to run it with command `java -cp target/file.jar -DmainClass ru.dmteam.App`. Is it possible to create jar with right manifest?

Comment: The <executions> component should bind the assembly creation to the normal package phase, have you included it in your pom.xml? The <archive> entry should be configured to contained the <mainClass> ru.dmteam.App in your case.

Comment: When I changed maven version to 2.2-beta-3 all problems gone! Thanks.

Comment: When I run `java -jar xxx.jar`, the classpath is messed up, throwing `Could not resolve substitution to a value: ${spray.version}`. Any ideas how to set the correct classpath?

Answer (score -2):

you can run the jar this way

scala -cp target/projectname-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar